# Ranked Feed Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, feed, ranking

I'm building a sports newsfeed for an app and I'd like it to be sorted on popularity as well as chronologically. I've implemented the sorting using the open-source reddit algorithm (my app has likes for each post in the newsfeed). So far I've tested it and it seems to be working well but there's one main problem I've encountered: News about popular sports always show up above news from other sports. Example: My app has 100,000 basketball fans and 1,000 soccer fans. A big news about soccer comes out. It'll still have less likes than the other regular daily basketball news. How can I resolve this issue? One possible solution I considered is feeding the reddit algorithm the % of all fans that liked a certain post.

Comment: You could do some simple division `popularity = likes / fan base`. There is really no perfect answer here, there might be other factors you want to consider as well. Try different formulas until you have the desired result

Comment: Please clarify your sorting; it's not possible to have both time and votes be *the* primary sort key.  How do you resolve this?

Comment: The sorting is done based on the reddit algorithm, which uses both the time and votes to assign a score.

Comment: Ah; Reddit packages the algorithm for you ... and you want to replace "votes" with a more balanced measure.

Comment: Yes exactly. If I just give the algorithm the number of likes it'll be skewed towards sports that have more fans overall. I'll try out @Mitchel0022 's suggestion and divides the likes by the fan base to get a more accurate number

Comment: The first thing you need to decide is what exactly does "resolve this issue" mean *for you*. It sounds like your system is currently working as intended - you want to sort on popularity and popular stories (about basketball) are being sorted above less popular stories (about soccer). Maybe you want to give a greater weight to 'newness', maybe something else - but first *you need to decide what you want*

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you normalize the percentage across your fan base.  "Popularity" should measure not only percentage of up-votes, but relative percentage within the fan base.

For each article, count the up-votes.  Next, convert this to a Z-score: how many standard deviations above/below the mean this article was rated, within the fan base for that sport.  Use this in place of the quantity of votes.

Comment: Good answer. Would be a good addition if you explained why this would be qualitatively superior over normalizing via simply dividing by the size of the total fan base.

Comment: OP already highlighted the problem of dividing by the total population.  Z-score includes a normalization for the population voting on that article.